# Android create circular progressbar with image gradient

Tags: android

I have got image with gradient and i want create circular progress bar with that image.In all example people create circular progress bar using shape and then gradient something like that :

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <shape
             android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
             android:shape="ring"
             android:thicknessRatio="7.0">
  <gradient
             android:startColor="#fb0000"
             android:endColor="#00FF00"
             android:centerColor="#fbf400"
             android:type="sweep" />   
</shape>
</item>
```

But i want to using my own image not gradient its possible ?

Im creating something like that but its not working:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"        >
        <clip>
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="25.0">

            </shape>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/progress_background"></bitmap>


        </clip>
    </item>
```

This is my image :
[image: progress background]

And i want to achieve circular progress bar like that: 
[image]

Comment: sure, define a RotateDrawable in res/drawable

Comment: is it part of layer-list or something?

Comment: Yes its part of layer list

Comment: did you try rotate tag?

Comment: No i have not any idea about rotate, i think that its not problem with rotate my image but something else

Comment: so try it,  it has android:drawable attribute

Comment: i change clip ---> rotate but its not working

Comment: sorry i don't have a crystal  ball and cannot read your unposted code